# show all weekends between 2 dates in groups

Tags: php

I trying to show the weekends between 2 dates in a formatted way.

For an example:

```
$start = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$end = strtotime(2018-06-12);

for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i = strtotime("+1 day", $i)) {

//show weekends as 
// saturday and sunday - march 24-25, 2018
// saturday - march 31, 2018
// sunday - april 1, 2018
// saturday and sunday - april 7-8, 2018
//.........



}
```

If you can see above i need to group the weekend and if the saturday and sunday falls in 2 different months show them separately.

Can someone please help me how to do this?

Comment: What if start is Sunday? Only output Sunday or skip that weekend? And `saturday and sunday - march 25-28, 2018`, Saturday and Sunday is two days. You say 25-28, that's four days.

Comment: @Andreas if its sunday i need to show only the sunday.. There was a small mistake.. it should be  `saturday and sunday - march 24-25, 2018` i edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
$start = strtotime('2018-03-18');
$end = strtotime('2018-06-12');

for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i = strtotime("+1 day", $i)) {

    if (date('w', $i) == 6) {
        list ($currentDate, $currentMonth, $currentYear) = explode(' ', date('j F Y', $i));
        $i = strtotime("+1 day", $i);
        list ($nextDate, $nextMonth, $nextYear) = explode(' ', date('j F Y', $i));

        if ($currentMonth == $nextMonth) {
            echo 'Saturday and Sunday - ' . $currentMonth. ' ' . $currentDate . '-' . ($currentDate + 1) . ', ' . $currentYear . PHP_EOL;
            continue;
        }

        echo 'Saturday - ' . $currentMonth . ' ' . $currentDate . ', ' . $currentYear . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Sunday - ' . $nextMonth . ' ' . $nextDate . ', ' . $nextYear . PHP_EOL;
        continue;
    } elseif (date('w', $i) == 0) {
        echo 'Sunday - ' . date('F j, Y', $i) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method which creates an array that I later can implode to get the string format you want.
The array is built on year, month, week and day.
Then it's just a matter of iterating and echoing.

```
$start = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$end = strtotime("2018-06-12");


for ($i = $start; $i <= $end;) {
    If(date("N", $i) == 6){
        $arr[date("Y", $i)][date("F", $i)][date("W", $i)][date("l", $i)] = date("d", $i);
        $i+= 86400;
        $arr[date("Y", $i)][date("F", $i)][date("W", $i)][date("l", $i)] = date("d", $i);
        $i+= 86400*6;
    }Else If(date("N", $i) == 7){
        $arr[date("Y", $i)][date("F", $i)][date("W", $i)][date("l", $i)] = date("d", $i);
        $i+= 86400*6;
    }Else{
        $i+= 86400;
    }
}

Foreach($arr as $year => $years){
    Foreach($years as $month => $months){
        Foreach($months as $week){
            Echo implode(" and ",array_keys($week)) . " - " . $month . " " . Implode("-", $week) . ", ". $year . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/nHe0d

Edit: forgot to output month.
Edit 2: changed the initial loop to not loop all days. Should make it slightly faster.
Edit 3: found a bug in the code. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$start = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$end = strtotime('2018-06-12');

for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i = strtotime("+1 day", $i)) {
    $date =  date('D Y-m-d N', $i);
    $n = (int)date('N', $i);
    if ($n > 5) {
        echo $date . '<hr>';
    }
}
```

date('N', $i) will give you number of the weekday(1-monday, 7-sunday)

And you check if its greater than 5(6 or 7) (Saturday or Sunday)